# Get back ownership of DevOps organization that was created by me

Tags: azure-devops

We have a company DevOps organization that was created by me and I was the active owner, the ownership was transferred to an external developer to setup build and other settings for a project. The ownership remained in his name and he is not active on the project anymore.

When I try to access the site it shows that it was deleted and me as (Member) at the end. Is there any way to re-gain access to this organization and recover it?

The DevOps organization was never linked to our AD and was setup separately by my self, I have proof that I did the setup, and the organization name is our company name.

Comment: Sounds more like a customer support case.

Answer (score 0):

To recover a deleted organization in Azure DevOps, you need to meet the following requests:

- An organization deleted within the last 28 days.
- Organization Owner permissions to restore your organization.

To change the organization owner, you must be a Project Collection Administrator or an organization Owner. It seems you don't have these permissions, so you need to contact [Azure DevOps Support](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html).

Useful links:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/recover-your-organization?view=azure-devops
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/change-organization-ownership?view=azure-devops

Comment: Have you checked my reply? Is my reply helpful?